# How correct work with global variables in Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Global.asax file in my project with code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using WrapperObjects;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Application
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        private string userLogin = string.Empty;
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            

        }

        void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                               

        }

        void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DBUsers.SetUserStatusOnline("0", userLogin);   
            Session["curUserRole"] = string.Empty;
            Session["curUserLogin"] = string.Empty;
        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
            if (app.Request.IsAuthenticated && User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
            {
                SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.GetConnectionString());
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE login=@login", myConnection);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("login", app.Context.User.Identity.Name);
                myCommand.Connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader Reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                string role = string.Empty;                
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    userLogin = Reader["login"].ToString();
                    role = Reader["role"].ToString();
                }
                if (role != string.Empty)
                {
                    FormsIdentity fi = (FormsIdentity)app.User.Identity;
                    app.Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(fi, new string[] { role });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When user login into the project run function `protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)` and I try to store user login in private string type `userLogin` variable. But when session end run function `void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)` in this function I try to save in database by user login status "offline" but variable `userLogin` is empty. Where I can quickly save user login and get it in function `void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)`?

Comment: Either change `userLogin` to `static` or save it at the `Session`

Comment: If the Context.User.Identity.Name is the same as userLogin, then use Context.User.Identity.Name. If not, save the userLogin value to the session instead. Do NOT make the variable "userLogin" static. It is better to save it in the Session.

Answer (score 1):

Because of stateless of web applications you can't do this through static variable.
If I where you, I would save login to Session state in

```
 protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        if (app.Request.IsAuthenticated && User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.GetConnectionString());
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE login=@login", myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("login", app.Context.User.Identity.Name);
            myCommand.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader Reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            var userLogin = string.Empty;
            string role = string.Empty;                
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                userLogin = Reader["login"].ToString();
                role = Reader["role"].ToString();
            }
            if (role != string.Empty)
            {
                FormsIdentity fi = (FormsIdentity)app.User.Identity;
                app.Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(fi, new string[] { role });
                Session["UserLogin"] = userLogin;
            }
        }
    }
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if(Session["UserLogin"]!=null)
        {
            var userLogin = (string)Session["UserLogin"];
            DBUsers.SetUserStatusOnline("0", userLogin); 
        }              
    }
```

Comment: In this way: (string)Session["UserLogin"] = null

Comment: Are you sure that Application_AuthenticateRequest was invoked before this?